# Is it possible to add a COM reference in the latest versions of ASP.NET Core?

Tags: dll, com, asp.net-core-2.0, dllregistration

We have a software, which has a COM interface to communicate with. I have to build a Web Service for an app to access data of the software and I want to build it in **ASP.NET Core**.

I cannot find *COM section* in *Add Reference* dialog. There is just a Browse section to add external assemblies. I added the **type library of the COM DLL** but it did not work. The server gave **502** error.

Event viewer had this error after the request:

```
Faulting application name: AspNetCoreDemo.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time 
stamp: 0x5bca0f4b
Faulting module name: coreclr.dll, version: 4.6.27019.6, time stamp: 
0x5bc9ebee
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000050318
Faulting process id: 0x17cc
...
```

Is there any solution to **use COM library with ASP.NET Core projects**, or I have to develop apps with the old ASP.NET .NET framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding COM Objects to Asp Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866103/adding-com-objects-to-asp-net-core)

Comment: Thank you. It was not appearing on my search, just for the missing keyword "Interop".)