# Is there any way to use ABBYY FRE on .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, abbyy, finereader

I am developing application using .NET Core console application.

And I need to use [ABBYY FRE](https://www.abbyy.com/en-eu/support/engine/12/product_info/sr/?expandedclosed) in my project.

I have developed .NET Framework 4.5 application previously. I have used FRE using **COM** object. And it works very well.

But .NET Core works with **COM** objects not very well. Details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866103/adding-com-objects-to-asp-net-core).

Is there any way to use ABBYY FRE on .NET Core???

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's a bit irrelevant to exact question, but if you are using COM object it means that you are bound to windows, so why you ever need .Net core? Just use .net framework.

Comment: I have some big parts in my project. I need to implement Web app in one part. For Web app we use AWS Lambda on .NET Core. AWS Lambda does not work with .NET Framework. So I try to use .NET Core for other parts in my app.

Comment: @AlexanderI. [COM interop does work on .NET Core](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Jan/22/COM-Object-Access-and-dynamic-in-NET-Core-2x) but only on Windows. That's what the linked question says, not that it doesn't work well

Comment: @AlexanderI. the *important* information though is that you want to deploy to AWS Lambda. That means the OS may *not* be Windows at all and you may *not* be able to deploy the DLLs you want. Even if you could, you may increase the Lambda's startup time. In this case an HTTP-based OCR is preferable

Comment: @AramKocharyan .NET Core is the *current* actively developed .NET version, even on Windows. You may have heard that ASP.NET Core 3.0 will *not* be available for .NET Framework even though previous versions were. .NET Framework is essentially in maintenance mode

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have no use AWS Lambda for FRE OCR. I use Lambda for other part of my application (semple WebAPI). I try to use FRE OCR on EC2 instanse. EC2 instance has Windows OS. Currently I use .NetFramework for FRE OCR and .NET Core for other parts of my project. It works, but we have two frameworks in solution. And I try to find more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External assemblies that target .Net framework should only be used against the framework. Though .Net standard 2.0 applications can be ported to work with .net framework 4.6 and .Net core 2.0, FRE interop dlls are specifically targets .Net framework. So, there's no reason to use them in .net core.

The FRE dlls need windows runtime to work. Unless abbyy releases a package and version for .Net.core, the only way to go.is .net framework and Windows server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such opportunity for today.

If your application has the opportunity and allows the script, then you can use the [Cloud OCR SDK](https://www.ocrsdk.com/) service (inside, from April there will be the latest version of FRE).

Comment: Thanks. We know about Cloud OCR SDK. But we need to use FRE in our solution. Please review my last comment for @PanagiotisKanavos. It can help to understand  situation.